# How can you restrict a method parameter based on an enum?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

I feel like this is an anti pattern of some sort, but basically I've got 2 versions of the same type of repo that have the same type of properties and methods. I played with the idea of both an interface and an abstract class but in neither case can I get around what appears to be unnecessary checks. Here's the premise (using abstract class):

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    public abstract RepositoryType RepositoryType { get; } //enum of File or DataBase
    public abstract CreateResult CreateItem (Item item);
    public abstract DeleteResult DeleteItemById(Guid Id);
    public abstract Item GetItem(Guid Id);
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public ItemType ItemType { get; } //enum of File or DataRecord
    
    //other props...
}

public FileRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public override RepositoryType RepositoryType => RepositoryType.File
    
    public override CreateResult CreateItem(Item item)
    {
        if(item.ItemType != ItemType.File) throw InvalidOperationException("some error message") //problem is here

        //some logic.
    }

    //other overrides....
}
```

So there's a basic contract created for a repository via the BaseRepository, which is overridden by the FileRepository. An item basically has the same stuff whether it's a File item or a DataRecord item (there could arguably be an IItem interface and then 2 separate Items of DataRecord and File rather than an enum but that still doesn't solve the problem).

The problem is I don't see how I can pass in an Item with only ItemType File to the FileRepository. It feels like there should be a way of making sure that the FileRepository only receives items of type File and that a check shouldn't have to be made to ensure it's got the right type. How can I do this?

Comment: generics ?..... `BaseRepository<TItem>` with `Create(TItem item)` where `TItem` implements a common interface?

Comment: Food for thought: I'd challenge whether you want this base class or interface in the first place. Do you ever want to work with a BaseRepository, not knowing whether it's a FileRepository or a DataRecordRepository (or anything else)? Even if the methods look similar, they seem like fairly different things to me. Moreover, they might evolve in a different direction and look completely different tomorrow.

Comment: @MatthiasMeid - interesting challenge, and I actually did wonder that myself as the logic in the implementations is completely different. However, I've simplified the code perhaps a little too much in the question. This isn't really a BaseRepository, but more a specific type of base repository, let's call it a DataRepository. During app setup it can be configured to use a different data approach, but they must essentially work in the same way, which is why I ended up opting with the abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the repository generic, and introduce types for each type of item. eg:

```
public abstract class Item
{

}
public class FileItem : Item
{

}
public abstract class Repository<TItem> where TItem : Item
{
    public virtual string RepositoryType => typeof(TItem).Name;
    public abstract CreateResult CreateItem(TItem item);
    public abstract DeleteResult DeleteItemById(Guid Id);
    public abstract Item GetItem(Guid Id);
}

public class FileRepository : Repository<FileItem>
{
    public override CreateResult CreateItem(FileItem item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override DeleteResult DeleteItemById(Guid Id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Item GetItem(Guid Id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! I couldn't see the wood from the trees. Thanks very much.